# How do I filter <li> under a<ul> having a particular id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, freemarker

```
        <ul class="apple" id="A">
             <li>
             <li>
              .....
              ......
              ......

        </ul>

         <ul class="apple" id="B">
             <li>
             <li>
              .....
              ......
              ......

        </ul>
```

In the above code I get the ul having id B using jQuery selector.

$(selector).find('ul.apple #B')  This does not seem to work.

I want to display all the li under the ul having class=apple & id ="B" . The above code is in FTL ( freemarker) & I am trying to trigger the id written in freemarker from the js code.

Thanks :)

Comment: How about `$('ul.apple#B > li')`?

Comment: The `<ul>` is under the `<ul>` and not under the `<li>`. Am I missing something? `$('ul.apple#A').next('ul.apple#B li');`

Comment: there are two separate ul with same class name and different id's . There is no ul under ul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id's should be unique in a document. You never need to include any other selector but the id itself `$('#B')`. No need for `.find` or anything - there's only one on the page anyway.

If you want a reference to the `li` tags under `#B`, here are two ways:

```
//get a reference to the list
var $B = $('#B');
//get children (which are lis)
var $lis = $B.children();
```

or just get the lis directly:

```
var $lis = $('#B li');
```

Comment: yeah the above works perfect in the console but when I write it in the code it does not seem to show me anything on the page

Comment: @user2821242 you have to do something with them. This is just getting a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Normall you only need to specify the id, as it's unique in the page, so a selector like this would work:

```
#B li
```

If you still need to specify the element and class, for example if you are using the same CSS for several pages, you would specify them without spaces between:

```
ul.apple#b li
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id), it is specified that **element IDs must be unique**.

That said, you can just query by the id via:

```
$('#A');
```

Answer (score 0):

select UI by id and class name:
$('B .apple')